# Random number generator does not work

Tags: python, random

I am trying to create a random number in Python. For some reason the code shown below does not work.

```
import random    
print random.random()
```

I receive the following error:

> invalid syntax

If anyone has any pointers, I will greatly appreciate it.

P.S. The above code works on some computers (2 out of 30 in a room).

Comment: Are you using Python3? Then `print` is a function that you have to call like `print(random.random())`

Answer (score 3):

If python 3 is being used, then print is a function and must be called like

```
print (random.random())
```

This would also explain why the code works on two computers. They might be running a different version of python.